# How to use getopt in bash command line with only long options?

Tags: shell, command

There is a `getopt` command in bash command line. `getopt` can used with short options (such as `getopt -o axby "$@"`), and can be used with both short and long options (such as `getopt -o axby -l long-key -- "$@"`), but now I need *only* long options (i.e. short options don't exist at all), however the command `getopt -l long-key -- "$@"` doesn't parse `--long-key` option correctly. So how can I use `getopt` command with *only* long options? Or is it impossible or is it just a bug of the `getopt` command?

Comment: You tag for the internal `getopts`, but you are using the `/usr/bin/getopt` command.

Comment: @Anthon  Sorry, I have used the wrong tag, but I haven't got enough reputations to add another tag, which needs 300 reputations. However, I have deleted the wrong tag just now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`getopt` is perfectly fine with having no short options. But you need to tell it that you have no short options. It's a quirk in the syntax — from the manual:

> If no `-o` or `--options` option is  found  in the first part, the first parameter of the second part is used as the short options string.

That's what's happening in your test: `getopt -l long-key -- --long-key foo` treats `--long-key` as the list of options `-egklnoy` and `foo` as the sole argument. Use

```
getopt -o '' -l long-key -- "$@"
```

e.g.

```
$ getopt -l long-key -o '' -- --long-key foo
 --long-key -- 'foo'
$ getopt -l long-key -o '' -- --long-key --not-recognized -n foo
getopt: unrecognized option '--not-recognized'
getopt: invalid option -- 'n'
 --long-key -- 'foo'
```

Comment: Did the OP's mixing of `getopts` and `getopt` infect to your answer? You start with commenting `getopts` then only mention `getopt`.

Comment: @Anthon All my answer is about the `getopt` program from GNU coreutils which is what the question is about. I've fixed the text that said `getopts`. Thanks. `getopts` doesn't even do long options, so none of this would apply to `getopts`.

Comment: The OP originally had the `getopts` tag. I did not want to change your answer, because you normally know much better than I what you are writing about :-)

Comment: I lost almost an hour trying to figure this out. You just saved me a few vain coffee sips. Thanks... lets put this coffee to a better use now. ☕️

Comment: Why do you put the symbol `--` after `-o ' '`

Answer (score 1):

Dunno about `getopt` but the `getopts` builtin can be used to handle only long options like this:

```
while getopts :-: o
do  case "$o$OPTARG" in
(-longopt1) process ;;
(-longopt2) process ;;
esac; done
```

Of course, as is, that doesn't work if the long-options are supposed to have arguments. It can be done, though, but, as I've learned working on this. While I initially included it here I realized that for long-options it doesn't have much utility. In this case it was only shortening my `case` `(match)` fields by a single, predictable character. Now, what I know, is that it is excellent for short options - it is most useful when it is looping over a string of unknown length and selecting single bytes according to its option-string. But when the option *is* the arg, there's not a lot you're doing with a `for var do case $var in` combination that it could do. It is better, I think, to keep it simple.

I suspect the same is true of `getopt` but I don't know enough about it to say with any certainty. Given the following arg array, I will demonstrate my own little arg parser - which depends primarily on the evalation/assignment relationship I've come to appreciate for `alias` and `$((shell=math))`.

```
set -- this is ignored by default --lopt1 -s 'some '\'' 
args' here --ignored   and these are ignored \
--alsoignored andthis --lopt2 'and 

some "`more' --lopt1 and just a few more
```

That's the arg string I'll be working with. Now:

```
aopts() { env - sh -s -- "$@"
} <<OPTCASE 3<<\OPTSCRIPT
acase() case "\$a" in $(fmt='
        (%s) f=%s; aset "?$(($f)):";;\n'
        for a do case "$a" in (--) break;;
        (--*[!_[:alnum:]]*) continue;;
        (--*) printf "$fmt" "$a" "${a#--}";;
        esac;done;printf "$fmt" '--*' ignored)
        (*) aset "" "\$a";;esac
shift "$((SHIFT$$))"; f=ignored; exec <&3 
OPTCASE
aset()  {  alias "$f=$(($f${1:-=$(($f))+}1))"
        [ -n "${2+?}" ] && alias "${f}_$(($f))=$2"; }
for a do acase; done; alias
#END
OPTSCRIPT
```

That processes the arg array in one of two different ways depending on whether you hand it one or two sets of arguments separated by the `--` delimiter. In both cases it applies to sequences of processing to the arg array.

If you call it like:

```
: $((SHIFT$$=3)); aopts --lopt1 --lopt2 -- "$@"
```

Its first order of business will be to write its `acase()` function to look like:

```
acase() case "$a" in 
    (--lopt1) f=lopt1; aset "?$(($f)):";;
    (--lopt2) f=lopt2; aset "?$(($f)):";;
    (--*) f=ignored; aset "?$(($f)):";;
    (*) aset "" "$a";;esac
```

And next to `shift 3`. The command-substitution in the `acase()` function definition is evaluated when the calling shell builds the function's input here-documents, but `acase()` is never called or defined in the calling shell. It is called in the subshell, though, of course, and so this way you can dynamically specify the options of interest on the command line.

If you hand it an un-delimited array it simply populates `acase()` with matches for all arguments beginning with the string `--`.

The function does practically all of its processing in the subshell - iteratively saving each of the arg's values to aliases assigned with associative names. When it is through it prints out every value it saved with `alias` - which is POSIX-specified to print all saved values quoted in such a way that their values can be reinput to the shell. So when I do...

```
aopts --lopt1 --lopt2 -- "$@"
```

Its output looks like this:

```
...ignored...
lopt1='8'
lopt1_1='-s'
lopt1_2='some '\'' args'
lopt1_3='here'
lopt1_4='and'
lopt1_5='just'
lopt1_6='a'
lopt1_7='few'
lopt1_8='more'
lopt2='1'
lopt2_1='and

some "`more'
```

As it walks through the arg list it checks against the case block for a match. If it finds a match there it throws a flag - `f=optname`. Until it once again finds a valid option it will add each subsequent arg to an array it builds based on the current flag. If the same option is specified multiple times the results compound and do not override. Anything not in case - or any arguments following ignored options - are assigned to an *ignored* array.

The output is shell-safed for shell-input automatically by the shell, and so:

```
eval "$(: $((SHIFT$$=3));aopts --lopt1 --lopt2 -- "$@")"
```

...should be perfectly safe. If it for any reason *is not* safe, then you should probably file a bug report with your shell maintainer.

It assigns two kinds of alias values for each match. First, it sets a flag - this occurs whether or not an option precedes non-matching arguments. So any occurrence of `--flag` in the arg list will trigger `flag=1`. This does not compound - `--flag --flag --flag` just gets `flag=1`. This value *does* increment though - for any arguments that might follow it. It can be used as an index key. After doing the `eval` above I can do:

```
printf %s\\n "$lopt1" "$lopt2"
```

...to get...

```
8
1
```

And so:

```
for o in lopt1 lopt2
do list= i=0; echo "$o = $(($o))"
        while [ "$((i=$i+1))" -le "$(($o))" ]
        do list="$list $o $i \"\${${o}_$i}\" "
done; eval "printf '%s[%02d] = %s\n' $list";  done
```

#### OUTPUT

```
lopt1 = 8
lopt1[01] = -s
lopt1[02] = some ' args
lopt1[03] = here
lopt1[04] = and
lopt1[05] = just
lopt1[06] = a
lopt1[07] = few
lopt1[08] = more
lopt2 = 1
lopt2[01] = and

some "`more
```

And to args which did not match I would substitute *ignored* in the above `for ... in` field to get:

```
ignored = 10
ignored[01] = this
ignored[02] = is
ignored[03] = ignored
ignored[04] = by
ignored[05] = default
ignored[06] = and
ignored[07] = these
ignored[08] = are
ignored[09] = ignored
ignored[10] = andthis
```